# <%@ page import ="com.sql.*" %> error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am new in Java.
I am trying to develop a Dynamic Web Application.
I have set up the Tomcat, and Wamp server.
I have added MySQL library to my program.
I have imported the database and available.

But when I started programming, I get this error message on line 3:

> <%@ page import ="com.sql.*" %>” in “The import com.sql cannot be
>   resolved

Here is my code. Do you have any suggestions?

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import ="com.sql.*" %>
```

Comment: And what do you want to import with that?

Answer (score 0):

It should be-

```
<%@ page import="com.mysql.*" %>
```